# Set MultiSubnetfalilver=Yes to linked servers in standalone SQL Server 2016 implications

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am using 1 node SQL Server 2016, having linked servers using MSOLEDBSQL provider and Provider string "MultiSubnetFailover=Yes". 
Are there any implications/negative impacts, if i use "MultiSubnetFailover=Yes" to create linked servers in standalone SQL Server 2016.
OR "MultiSubnetFailover=Yes" should only be used in Alwayson setup.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a benefit of using `MultiSubnetFailover` for a sandalone server since you dont have failovers, no listener is configured and its a single point of failure. There is obviously a [performance gain when using `MultiSubnetFailover`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/224215/8783) in a DR situation.

Comment: Is it possible to use 'MultiSubnetFailover=Yes' with SQLNCLI11 or SQLOLEDB? Or only with MSOLEDBSQL?