# Record MultiSubnetFailover value at connection?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, connections

With AlwaysOn, there are 3 options for the keyword `MultiSubnetFailover`

- True (yes)
- False (no) [(*example*)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252232/21924)
- Not sent/used

Not all applications support it's use in connection strings. Not all vendor contacts understand it's importance to performance at failover.

As a DBA I would like to be able to validate what property is being used by the application connection.  If I have not made the appropriate setting change to `RegisterAllProvidersIP` it can cause issues.  See: [Follow-up: After Creating an Availability Group Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#FollowUp)

It does not appear to be capture in either [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) nor [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

How can I capture what (*if any*) keyword values were used to create a connection to one of my instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this configuration setting is sent to the server.  It controls the client's interpretation of a DNS lookup returning multiple IP addresses, and there is no functional need for the server to be informed about it.  And the client doesn't send arbitrary name/value pairs to the server.  The fields that a client sends to the server are dictated by the [TDS protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/ce5ad23f-6bf8-4fa5-9426-6b0d36e14da2), and it would require a protocol revision to add new ones.

Also while properly setting MultSubnetFailover at the client continues to be a best-practice, newer SQL Server client libraries have changed their behavior to mitigate the issues arising from not setting MultiSubnetFailover.  See [Using Transparent Network IP Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-transparent-network-ip-resolution?view=sql-server-ver15).  Newer clients will have only a brief delay in connecting when the first IP returned from DNS is not the active AG Listener, instead of the old behavior of waiting 20-30 seconds before attempting to connect to the second IP.